# What is the difference between the INVITE field and the To field in a SIP INVITE message?

Tags: sip, ims

In a SIP INVITE message, what is the difference between the INVITE field address and the To field in the Message Header? Shouldn't the SIP URI in the INVITE field the same as SIP URI in the 'To' field in the message header?

Thanks

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about the difference between RequestUri and To Uri.

Request URI  :

**INVITE sip:+919100548751@85.13.246.222 SIP/2.0**

To URI  :

**sip:+919100548751@52.10.15.196;transport=UDP**

The differece between them is Request Uri contain the next HOP ip adrress where as to uri contains the destination Number.

From source to Destination address ...we can have many hops.

I hpoe i answered your question

Answer (score 1):

For a request `URI` the specification [RFC3261 8.1.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-8.1.1.1) says:

> The initial Request-URI of the message SHOULD be set to the value of
> the URI in the To field.  One notable exception is the REGISTER
> method;

For the `To` header the specification [RFC3261 8.1.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-8.1.1.2) says:

> The To header field first and foremost specifies the desired
> "logical" recipient of the request, or the address-of-record of the
> user or resource that is the target of this request.  This may or may
> not be the ultimate recipient of the request.

For non-REGISTER requests the `To` header URI is a "logical" value and it's typically left up to the agent that processes the request to decide how to use it (often nothing is done with it). The request `URI` is much more critical. It dictates where and how the request needs to be sent.

One example that may help is when a request needs to be sent over a TCP transport. The request `URI` could get produced as:

```
sip:1234@localhost;transport=tcp
```

Whereas the `To` URI will remain:

```
 sip:1234@localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

*In a SIP INVITE message, what is the difference between the INVITE field address and the To field in the Message Header?*

The `'to'` header field contains the desired `address-of-record`; that `address-of-record` is constant in nature (with exceptions).
The INVITE field address aka `Request-URI` contains the current `SIP-URI` target and is variable in nature.

*Shouldn't the SIP URI in the INVITE field the same as SIP URI in the 'To' field in the message header?*

Short answer : Yes when forming the initial INVITE and no when SIP routing occurs.

Longer stuff : If the user agent Alice initiates a call to a specific Bob SIP endpoint, it retrieves the Bob address-of-record from **somewhere** and then create a initial INVITE request with the desired `address-of-record` placed in the `Request-URI` field, place the same `address-of-record` in the URI of the `to` header field.

The initial INVITE is sent and routed ... at one SIP proxy the  `Request-URI` field is refined using the procedure as specified in [RFC3261] section 16.

If it receives a request targeted at the address-of-record that belongs to the domain that this proxy is responsible for then :

- It is supposed to access a SIP location service to compute `the request targets`, note that more than one `target-URI` is possible!
- In a simple case, the request-URI is filed with registered contact of the desired `address-of-record` using REGISTRAR database.
- the proxy creates related `INVITE request` with the `request URI` changed to newly fetched `target URI`,
- then if more `target-URI` exist then proceed in the same way for forking purpose.